# PHP: Addition of values in multidimensional array where key equal to and equal to

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Having following array:

```
Array
(
    [notifys] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
        (
            [notifytype_id] => 10
            [notify_total] => 1
        )

        [1] => Array
        (
            [notifytype_id] => 11
            [notify_total] => 1
        )

        [2] => Array
        (
            [notifytype_id] => 14
            [notify_total] => 3
        )

        [3] => Array
        (
            [notifytype_id] => 14
            [notify_total] => 3
        )

        [4] => Array
        (
            [notifytype_id] => 14
            [notify_total] => 2
        )

        [5] => Array
        (
            [notifytype_id] => 14
            [notify_total] => 32
        )

        [6] => Array
        (
            [notifytype_id] => 14
            [notify_total] => 28
        )

        [7] => Array
        (
            [notifytype_id] => 14
            [notify_total] => 3
        )

        [8] => Array
        (
            [notifytype_id] => 14
            [notify_total] => 7
        )

        [9] => Array
        (
            [notifytype_id] => 2
            [notify_total] => 7
        )

        [10] => Array
        (
            [notifytype_id] => 2
            [notify_total] => 15
        )
    )
)
```

### ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Need a PHP solution to do an addition, in example, of all values in `[notify_total]` **WHERE** `[notifytype_id] == 10` **OR** `[notifytype_id] == 2`

So, the result in this example would be:

***$result = 23***

Comment: That's an `OR`, not an `AND`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/*
$arr - array to be searched in
$k   - allowed key to be compared with
You can specify the keys dynamically that you want to compare against.
*/

function getTotal($arr, $k){
    $temp = 0;                                   //initialization
    foreach($arr['notifys'] as $a){
        if( in_array($a['notifytype_id'], $k))
            $temp = $temp + $a['notify_total'];
    }
    return $temp;
}

//Hanky reminded me
$keys = array(2, 10);                            //for this case
echo getTotal($value, $keys);
```

Comment: Forgot to initialize `$keys`?

Comment: No. Actually, Its upto user. So, i have didnt initialized. I have purposefully made dynamic way for that. BTW, thanks for efforts.

Comment: A dynamic solution always wins!! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
$total=0;
foreach($myArray["notifys"] as $value)
{
  if($value["notifytype_id"]==10 || $value["notifytype_id"]==2)
  $total+=$value["notify_total"];
}
echo $total;
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$sum = 0; 
foreach ($array['notifys'] as $index => $data)
{
   if ($data['notifytype_id']==10 or $data['notifytype_id']==2)
   {
      $sum += $data['notify_total'];
   } 
}
print $sum;
```

Comment: Nope let it be. Since you wrote this answer yourself and didn't copy an existing answer, and this is helpful as well, there is no reason to delete it.

Answer (score 1):

Use [array_reduce()](https://www.php.net/array_reduce) for that.

PHP >=5.4:

```
$result = array_reduce($array['notifys'], function($temp, $item)
{
   $temp+=in_array($item['notifytype_id'], [2,10])?$item['notify_total']:0;
   return $temp;
},0);
```

PHP 5.3:

```
$result = array_reduce($array['notifys'], function($temp, $item)
{
   $temp+=in_array($item['notifytype_id'], array(2,10))?$item['notify_total']:0;
   return $temp;
},0);
```

PHP <=5.2:

```
$result = array_reduce($array['notifys'], create_function('$temp, $item', '
{
   $temp+=in_array($item["notifytype_id"], array(2,10))?$item["notify_total"]:0;
   return $temp;
}'),0);
```

Comment: Getting a white page with this function. You know why? And what's the advantage of using array_reduce()?

Comment: That depends of PHP version you using. Code above is for PHP >=5.4 (in 5.3 there are no short-array definition and in 5.2 or lower there are no closures via `function` definition)

Comment: Using PHP 5.3.3, Sorry :)

Comment: See my edit then (but really - upgrade your PHP. There's no reason to stay on ancient versions, and, if it's about hosting - just change it)